# Catch http code status in dataFilter

Tags: jquery

How i can  catch http code status in dataFilter? Have the following code:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    dataFilter: function (data) {
      //need know http status for change data

      return data;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using the dataFilter.  From the docs:

> **dataFilter(data, type)Function**
>   A function to be used to handle the raw response data of XMLHttpRequest.This is a pre-filtering function to sanitize the response. You should return the sanitized data. The function accepts two arguments: The raw data returned from the server and the 'dataType' parameter.

Plus the `ajaxSetup` that you are referencing is used to define default ajax settings for when you make a jQuery ajax call.  That code does not actually make an ajax call.

There is a `statusCode` attribute to the jQuery ajax method that has what you are looking for.  You could also use `success` and `error` which are called depending on the resulting status code.

Read up on all of this in the docs: [jQuery.ajax() API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)